# Move folder from team drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive, movefile

how do you change the parent of a folder in a team drive. AddParents / RemoveParents generates an error "in a team drive a file has only one parent" and you can only read access to the parent collection. Should I make a copy of the file and delete the existing file?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the parent folder first then add the new parent.

Or you can do an [update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) changing the parent from one to the next.

The main issue will be if this is even possible with team drive as your going to need to have the permission to do this.